# Conditional rendering when using Redux (pure component and non-pure component)?

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
const LoginPage = ({ auth, doLogin, doLogout }) => (


    <div>
      <NavBar auth={auth}/>
        <div className="row">
            <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}} className="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <LoginForm auth={auth} doLogin={doLogin} doLogout={doLogout}/>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

);

// Connects state to the props of this component
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
});

// Return a NEW component that is connected to the Store
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { doLogin, doLogout })(LoginPage);
```

Above is the code of the component called `LoginPage`.
It passes in the global state `auth` and two actions `doLogin` and `doLogout`. The `LoginForm` handles the user authentication, but I want to put another component called `Dashboad` and render it conditionally based on the `auth`'s status.

However, I am not sure how to conditionally render in a pure component.

I could change into a non-pure component, but then I am not sure how to pass in `auth`, `doLogin`, and `doLogout` into a non-pure component.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do almost everything you did in a non pure component in a pure component, except that PureComponent automatically does the shouldComponentUpdate by react itself to avoid unnecessary rerenders based on the shallow diffing of state and props.

If you want to conditionally render dashboard you can check the auth status from redux and use `this.props.history.push("/dashboard")` or `<Redirect to="/dashboard">` to navigate to Dashboard component

Comment: Then how can I do conditional rendering in my example above?

Comment: You should change the above component from a functional component to a `Component` or a `PureComponent` and inside the comonentDidMount or componentWillReceiveProps, you can check thee authStatus, and use the history or redirect to navigate to dashboard